# Flutter Get Firestore Documents stream by list of IDs

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am looking for a way to get a stream of documents by another stream of Ids, Let's say I have a stream of document Ids like so  `Stream<List<String>> docIds = ['3dd34334, '45454de', ...]` then I need to query another collection using the ids I already have please find my code below which returns an empty stream.

```
Stream<List<ViewModel>> matches(uid) async { 

  Stream<List<String>> docIds = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('matches')
      .where('match', arrayContains: uid)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList());

  return docIds.map((e) {
    e.map((e) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('matches')
        .doc(e)
        .collection("myCollection")
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (event) => event.docs.map((e) => ViewModel.fromJson(e.data())).toList(),
        ));
  }).toList();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create Streams in multiple ways,

**Using yield** Basic example:

```dart
Stream<List<int>> countStream(int to) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
    List<int> list = List<int>();
    yield list;
  }
}
```

Now with firebase firestore and [transforming the stream](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#transforming-an-existing-stream):

```dart
Stream<List<ViewModel>> matches(uid) async* {
   Stream<List<String>> docIds = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('matches')
      .where('match', arrayContains: uid)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList());
   await for (List<ViewModel> chunk in source) {
       // Do other operations if you need
       yield chunk
   }
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, can you please explain your answer a bit more, also please use a practical example

Comment: Which part does not work for you? Do you have an error message?
It is not clear from my side which underlying data in Firestore you have or what is the content of the intermediate variables.